# extjs combo override : why define this.addevents()?

Tags: extjs

In the existing ext js code in the application, a combo box is overriden like this:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.ComboBox, {
    nullable:true
    ,initComponent: Ext.form.ComboBox.prototype.initComponent.createSequence(function(){
        this.triggerConfig = {
            tag:'span', cls:'x-form-twin-triggers', cn:[
                {tag: "img", src: Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL, cls:'x-form-trigger '},
                {tag: "img", src: Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL, cls:'x-form-trigger x-form-clear-trigger'}
        ]};
        this.addEvents(
            'clear',
            'change'
        );

}})
```

Why do we need to define:

```
this.addEvents(
                'clear',
                'change'
            );
```

'change' is already defined as an event for combobox in extjs. 'clear' is not defined in extjs.

EDIT: Maybe a reference to the actual example will help: Here it is.
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?84300-Nullable-ComboBox&p=404222&langid=14

Comment: Indeed. Defining `change` is a bit strange, since it's inherited anyway feom `Ext.form.Field`. As far as `clear` go, maybe it is being used elsewhere. JavaScript gives you that nasty possibility to spread your definitions around, so it might not be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll see that there's this method defined there:

```
clearValue:Ext.form.ComboBox.prototype.clearValue.createSequence(function(){
        if(this.trigger_clear){
            this.trigger_clear.hide();
        }
        this.fireEvent('clear',  this);
        this.fireEvent('change', this);
    })
```

So both events are called with only one argument passed (being the combobox itself). I don't think it was necessary to define `change` event here, since it is inherited from `Ext.form.Field`. Also the signature of inherited `change` event is `(field, newValue, oldValue)` while here, only one argument is passed. Because of that, I think another name should be used for this event.